# How can I verify users the first time they log in?

Tags: 9

I was reading [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199283/how-to-login-into-drupal-8-using-the-rest-api) article. I would like to know how logging in with the REST API in Drupal 8 works. By default, when users log in, Drupal will verify username and password. After the login, the browser has a cookie for the created session.

> [image]

With the REST API, how can Drupal 8 verify users the first time they log in? After the login, how does it check the current login?

Comment: The same way really - it gives you tokens when you login/request a CSRF token, then you send cookies/headers along with subsequent requests containing those values

Comment: Thank you for help. I'm newbie, so can help me more detail. How can get CSRF token, post CSRF token to server.

Comment: John, do you need further information or clarification of my answer below? I'm happy improve it if required.

Comment: Why was the title of the question changed to remove "REST API"? The question is specifically about the REST API.

Comment: @imclean The question title doesn't need to contain all the details, which is practically impossible. Then, we don't need tags to be reported in the title too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Some feedback. I updated the title to contain only the pertinent details. It is not "impossible", it's 3 extra words. There are at least 2 (and probably more) similar questions which mention logging in with the REST API with their titles intact. I consider my answer a concise language independent description so should be easily discoverable via the title alone. You've given a generic response, was there a specific problem in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Log in to Drupal by POSTing the user credentials. Make sure you set the "Content-Type" header. This starts the user's session.

POST URL:

```
/user/login?_format=json
```

Header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

POST data:

```
{
  "name": "username",
  "pass": "password"
}
```

Successful response:

```
{
  "current_user":{
    "uid": "1",
    "roles":[
      "authenticated",
      "administrator"
    ],
    "name": "username"
  },
  "csrf_token":   "asda09820380_2238019280dk09n908asjdlkajdaoa",
  "logout_token": "asdasd09a8sdaslkdasl-asdasdklsajdlkasdjlksj"
}
```

Use the CSRF token in subsequent GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE etc. requests by setting the header:

```
X-CSRF-Token: asda09820380_2238019280dk09n908asjdlkajdaoa
```

To log out, use the logout token in a POST request. This ends the user's session.

```
/user/logout?_format=json&token=asdasd09a8sdaslkdasl-asdasdklsajdlkasdjlksj
```

GET login status:

```
/user/login_status?_format=json
```

GET token:

```
/rest/session/token
```

References:

- [JavaScript and Drupal 8 RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services)
- Change record: [Additional RPC endpoints: user/login user/login/status user/logout user/password/reset](https://www.drupal.org/node/2720655)

Comment: That's is good. But is difficult for the newbie. Can you take more info about login with postman. Table session stored session has login. And exited login. You can't login again, and can return any response.

Comment: Postman could be a separate question. But at first glance it doesn't automatically save the history of requests and responses so you need to manually click "Save" each time. I use [Restlet Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-rest-api-t/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm). In Postman, make sure you only add the "Content-Type" header and for the body type click "raw". You need to "Save" each response so you can use the tokens again. Drupal sessions are managed the same way as normal. Client side you need to manually manage the tokens for the session.

Comment: No cookies are set with REST unless your app sets them. Use the tokens instead.

Comment: @Jonh It looks like Postman doesn't support saving REST responses so I recommend using Restlet client. See: [Save responses inside history and collections](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/622)

Comment: I found some problem. Table **sessions:  Drupal's session handlers read and write into the sessions table. Each record represents a user session, either anonymous or authenticated.** Controller  **/rest/session/token** always return value (any user anonymous or authenticated). So if you get token you need login with user first. When /user/login_status?_format=json return value 1. You can't login again to get token. You need logout. If can't logout. You can empty table sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal Core version: **8.x-4.x**

You need to enable the user login service first thing, this may be accomplished in so many ways, I prefer using [REST UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui) module.

Go to **/admin/config/services/rest** and enable **User** Rest resource.

Once enabled it you can go to **/admin/config/services/rest/resource/entity%3Auser/edit** by clicking on **Edit** next to the **User** resource. Make sure to enable the **GET** method.

[image]

Now you have everything setup, you can start using the service by running this command in the terminal or by using any application for curl requests like: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and [Restlet](https://restlet.com/modules/client/) clients.

**NOTE**: CSRF Token can be obtained from: ***/rest/session/token***

```
curl -i -L -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Accept:application/json" \
  -H "X-CSRF-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" \
  -d \
     '{
       "name": "my_username",
       "pass": "my_password"
     }' \
'http://SITE-URL/user/login?_format=json'
```

**The return objects are as below:**

***SUCCESS***:

```
{
  "current_user": {
  "uid": "1",
    "roles": [
      "authenticated"
    ],
    "name": "Admin"
  },
  "csrf_token": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
  "logout_token": "ccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
}
```

***FAILURE***:

```
{
  "message":"Sorry, unrecognized username or password."
}
```