# Rest login cookie token explanation

Tags: 8, users, sessions, cookies

When logging in via a POST to `user/login?_format=json`
I'm sent back a response that looks like this

```
{
    "current_user": {
        "uid": "233",
        "name": "test"
    },
    "csrf_token": "XXXXXR5HQwidW7CKIDL52tOg4JGKi7Pa-j87KKlr8Mg",
    "logout_token": "XXXX-G35feFznaapSggzlUQEhYKXqom6yYVDwCH5Zxc"
}
```

I'm also sent back a session cookie that looks like this

name: `SESS95f37088bf4f23c4304d24270b7xxxxx`

value: `rqAupOwS2ieqwClBkwEaWj8-ywLqnQEcAL2xOG-xxxx`

When I send a GET to `session/token`

I receive a seperate token that looks like this `_XXXXXnX8k_prCNfdrHp6XeHOUx7DcuouqiLKBBn-Go`

I understand that the logout token is used with `/user/logout` in order remove the cookie and log the user out.

My questions are as follows.

The Cross Site Request Forgery token doesn't seem to be required by any of my end points by default. Is this something I should have the backend require them on specific paths using `_csrf_token: 'TRUE'` (and be passing with each request using the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header?) Is this automatically passed with the cookie by chance?

The same question goes for the session token from `session/token` should this be being passed with each request, or in general what is the purpose for this token? I've seen this token referenced in docs as another CSRF token. If this is the case why is it different than the one provided by the login POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are logging in correctly by POSTing the username and password. After you've logged in, a Drupal session is created.

The `csrf_token` can be used to authorise future requests requests by sending it as a header:

```
X-CSRF-Token: XXXXXR5HQwidW7CKIDL52tOg4JGKi7Pa-j87KKlr8Mg
```

You can send this instead of a cookie if you've configured the backend to allow it. I've only used the [CORS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cors) contrib module as CORS in Drupal core doesn't have the same flexibility.

> I understand that the logout token is used with /user/logout in order
>   remove the cookie and log the user out.

Correct.

Also see my answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/235712/34673

Comment: You said instead of a cookie. Just confirming you wouldn't ever need to send both the X-CSRF-Token and the cookie? Is one considered more secure?

Comment: You can use either the header or the cookie, you don't need both. Each would be pretty secure I imagine, particularly if you're using SSL. I couldn't say for certain if one is more secure than the other.

Comment: Thinking about it, I think cookies are good when using non-destructive requests (GET). In such cases your JS library may take care of cookie authentication. When doing a POST or PATCH I believe the X-CSRF-Token header is required.

Comment: So cookies work for POST and PATCH, but are they secure?